# PowerShell - Remove item and Copy item

Tags: powershell

I have a version check function in the beginning of my script that is supposed to check the version of an .exe on a file share and compare it to the .exe on the users desktop. If the versions are different, it will remove the current desktop .exe and replace it with the one on the file share.

However, it won't replace it when run from the .exe, but it will work when I run it from PowerShell Studio or the ISE. I am compiling it with PowerShell Studio into the .exe file. Here is my code:

```
function global:VersionCheck
{
    # Get filepath of updated program
    $updatedprogram = (Get-Item \\fileshare\example\DeviceHealth\DeviceHealthV2.exe).VersionInfo | select -ExpandProperty FileVersion
    # Get version of current script on device
    $outdateprogram = (Get-Item c:\Users\$env:USERNAME\desktop\DeviceHealthV2.exe).VersionInfo | select -ExpandProperty FileVersion

    if ($updatedprogram -ne $outdateprogram)
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Program will be updated", "Out of Date")
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
        Remove-Item -Path "c:\Users\$env:USERNAME\desktop\DeviceHealthV2.exe" -Force
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
        Copy-Item -Path "\\fileshare\example\DeviceHealth\DeviceHealthV2.exe" -Destination "c:\Users\$env:USERNAME\desktop" -Force
    }
    else { }
}

VersionCheck
```

How do I determine why it is not working when I run it as an EXE file?

Comment: How is the executable being run? By the user or a service? Does whatever running have access to the share?

Comment: It is being ran as administrator from the desktop by the user. It does have access to the share, because it accesses other things on there.

Comment: Is the item that you are replacing the same executable that is being run? Are users launching DeviceHealthV2.exe, and you're trying to make it delete/replace itself?

Comment: Correct, it is exactly the same except for the file version. I am replacing DeviceHealthV2.exe with DeviceHealthV2.exe

Comment: Then you are running into a sharing violation. You cannot delete the executable while it is in use.

Comment: I just changed it to close the program, and then do it but it still does not work. I am guessing it is not accessing the file share right?

Comment: The script is running as an exe because you want to be able to double click? Or because you're executing it as some other user? If it's the latter, check the content of `$env:USERNAME` in the executing context.

Answer (score 0):

I found my obvious solution. I just created a separate script for the updater and changed my script to:

```
function global:VersionCheck
{
    # Get filepath of updated program
    $updatedprogram = (Get-Item \\fileshare\test\DeviceHealth\DeviceHealthV2.exe).VersionInfo | select -ExpandProperty FileVersion
    # Get version of current script on device
    $outdateprogram = (Get-Item c:\Users\$env:USERNAME\desktop\DeviceHealthV2.exe).VersionInfo | select -ExpandProperty FileVersion

    if ($updatedprogram -ne $outdateprogram)
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Program will be updated", "Out of Date")
        Start-Process "\\fileshare\test\scripts\Martin\PMCS\DeviceHealthUpdate.exe" -WindowStyle Hidden
    }
    else { }
}

VersionCheck
```

And in the update script I put:

```
Get-Process DeviceHealthV2 | Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null } | stop-process –force
Remove-Item -Path "c:\Users\$env:USERNAME\desktop\DeviceHealthV2.exe" -Force
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
Copy-Item -Path "\\fileshare\ask\DeviceHealth\DeviceHealthV2.exe" -Destination "c:\Users\$env:USERNAME\desktop" -Force
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
Start-Process "\\fileshare\ask\DeviceHealth\DeviceHealthV2.exe"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Update Successful", "Complete")
```

I tested it and it works great.